# Memoir: two different chapterstyles for parts and chapters

Tags: memoir

I want to use chapterstyle thatcher for the parts and chapterstyle veelo for the rest (chapters etc).

MMWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,openany]{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[german]{babel}

\usepackage[left=2.00cm, right=2.00cm, top=2.00cm, bottom=2.00cm]{geometry}

\chapterstyle{veelo} %-----------------------------> This for chapter etc

%part
\aliaspagestyle{part}{empty}
\usepackage{fmtcount}
\chapterstyle{thatcher}%-----------------------------------> This for parts ONLY

\renewcommand*{\thepart}{\arabic{part}}
\renewcommand*{\parttitlefont}{\normalfont\large\MakeUppercase}
\renewcommand*{\partnamefont}{\normalfont\scshape\MakeLowercase}
\renewcommand*{\partnumfont}{\normalfont\scshape\MakeLowercase}

\renewcommand*{\printpartname}{\partnamefont{\ordinalstring{part}[m] part}}
\renewcommand*{\printpartnum}{}

\renewcommand{\midpartskip}{\par\parbox{0.5in}{\hrulefill}\par}
\renewcommand{\beforepartskip}{\vspace*{\fill}}
\renewcommand{\afterpartskip}{\vspace*{\fill}}

\renewcommand*{\cftpartname}{Part}
\renewcommand*{\cftpartpresnum}{\space}
\renewcommand*{\cftpartaftersnum}{.}
\renewcommand*{\cftpartaftersnumb}{\space}


\begin{document}

\part{Love}
\chapter{Help}

\part{Is}
\chapter{Help}

\part{The}
\chapter{Help}

\part{Air}
\chapter{Help}

\end{document}
```

How it looks like up till now: https://docdro.id/cPVVpH8

In short: make veelo chapterstyle for the chapters.

Comment: Erh, your question does not make sense. Chapter styles apply to chapter headings not part headings, so don't load thatcher

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made some slight alterations to your MWE to give you what you want.

```
% memchapprob.tex SE 535653 different chapter styles

\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,openany]{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[german]{babel}

\usepackage[left=2.00cm, right=2.00cm, top=2.00cm, bottom=2.00cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{graphicx} % needed for the veelo chapterstyle
\chapterstyle{veelo} %-----------------------------> This for chapter etc

%part
\aliaspagestyle{part}{empty}
\usepackage{fmtcount}
%\chapterstyle{thatcher}%-----------------------------------> This for parts ONLY
                        % you have basically redefined \part to give this

\renewcommand*{\thepart}{\arabic{part}}
\renewcommand*{\parttitlefont}{\normalfont\large\MakeUppercase}
\renewcommand*{\partnamefont}{\normalfont\scshape\MakeLowercase}
\renewcommand*{\partnumfont}{\normalfont\scshape\MakeLowercase}

\renewcommand*{\printpartname}{\partnamefont{\ordinalstring{part}[m] part}}
\renewcommand*{\printpartnum}{}

\renewcommand{\midpartskip}{\par\parbox{0.5in}{\hrulefill}\par}
\renewcommand{\beforepartskip}{\vspace*{\fill}}
\renewcommand{\afterpartskip}{\vspace*{\fill}}

\renewcommand*{\cftpartname}{Part}
\renewcommand*{\cftpartpresnum}{\space}
\renewcommand*{\cftpartaftersnum}{.}
\renewcommand*{\cftpartaftersnumb}{\space}


\begin{document}

\part{Love}
\chapter{Help}

\part{Is}
\chapter{Help}

\part{The}
\chapter{Help}

\part{Air}
\chapter{Help}

\end{document}
```

Basically you have redefined `\part` to have the thatcher style, so no need for `\chapterstyle{thatcher}` just `\chapterstyle{veelo}`. But as stated in the manual you do need the `graphicx` package otherwise you get errors with `veelo`